GRUB2 not showing image background
I am trying to add a Grub2 custom graphic background to my system running AlmaLinux 9 (RedHat 9 clone).  My /etc/default/grub file is:
GRUB_FONT=fonts/unicode.pf2
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
#GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=1G-4G:192M,4G-64G:256M,64G-:512M resume=/dev/mapper/almalinux-swap rd.lvm.lv=almalinux/root rd.lvm.lv=almalinux/swap rhgb quiet"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="gfxterm"
GRUB_BACKGROUND="/boot/grub2/images/mylogo.png"

I have tried a 24bit PNG, 24bit JPG, and 8bit JPG (updating the background line accordingly), and after each change rerunning:
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/almalinux/grub.cfg
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg

My menu is present, as is the correct font, yet I still don't see ANY graphic background.  What am I missing?
My background image is 640x480.  Do I have to exactly match a screen size?  (I thought it would scale).
